# How to convert a local image file to a dataurl for use in image src

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am building a flash widget for uploading files, but I want to display the thumbnail with html/js, once I have the file loaded via Browse into flash and have access to the raw data, is there a way to convert that to a base64 encoded dataURL so I can send that back out to JS to create a thumbnail like ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this article](http://www.flepstudio.org/forum/tutorials/507-swf-png-actionscript-3-0-bytearray-class.html), as it describes how to convert a ByteArray into a png image.

ps: The PNGEncoder class is part of the **[as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib)**.